# Does anybody know of a SUPL 2.0 server?

Tags: gps, location, supl-2.0

I am looking for the `FQDN` of a `SUPL server`, version 2.0.  I know that `supl.google.com` exists but it is for version 1.0.

Please post the name and port number of a `SUPL 2.0 server` and let me know if it requires `TLS`.

FYI - `SUPL servers` are used to provide `assistance information` for `location` requests.

Answer (score 2):

Google SUPL server supports SUPL 2.0 specification. 
But as per my recent experiments, it supports only RRLP protocol. It does not support LPP protocol.
It only supports set based position calculations only( MS based). It does not support set assisted position calculations( MS assisted).

Comment: It seems that Google does support LPP/SUPL2.0 now. Check out this java implementation of a SUPL client using LPP to communicate with supl.google.com:

https://github.com/google/supl-client

Answer (score 1):

Google has recently started supporting SUPL 2.0 using the same FQDN. Make sure the device is camped on a WCDMA or LTE network.